# Deletion of comments

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

Only recently I discovered some of my comments being deleted only shortly after I wrote them (a couple of minutes). I know that comments are not meant to be persistent, but I never noticed it before and now I wonder...

- Is it common practice that comments get deleted even though they are not flagged? (Maybe because a different comment on the same question/answer got flagged and in the process of cleaning up also other comments get deleted?)
- Do I get a notification when one of my comments gets flagged or deleted because it was flagged?
- Did anything change recently that made moderators delete comments more frequently than before?

Comment: The thing is that useful comments are only those that hasn't been acted upon, after they are acted upon they become irrelevant. If they are acted upon a second or a millennia later they become immediately eligible for deletion.

Comment: @Braiam makes sense. Somehow any comment will be "no longer needed" at some point, flagging it just speeds it up. Actually I wasnt considering that a comment being flagged does not necessarily imply that there was something wrong with the comment (at the time it was written)

Comment: related: [Allow users to view flagged comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371385/839601) (also re-submitted to [CoC request for feedback here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312985/165773))

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In the last week, you've had 34 comments deleted. 6 of those were deleted by moderators, the remaining 28 you deleted yourself. Only one of the moderator-deleted comments was removed within minutes, the others were removed within 1-8 hours of being placed.

All of the moderator-removed comments were in response to flags. The one that was deleted within minutes was the most recent comment you had flagged, which is why this might appear to be a trend. I don't perceive such a trend among comment deletion times right now.

I deleted that comment, and got to it quickly simply because the queue of flagged comments had been worked down to nearly 0 at that time. Flag-handling time is variable. Queue size, number of flags on the same comment, type of flag, and time of day all play a role in how fast a moderator will handle a particular comment.

We do occasionally delete comments that have not been flagged, but that's usually because something else has drawn us to a post (an ongoing fight, flags on the post itself, etc.). Almost all comments that I see being deleted by moderators are in response to flags.

There are exceptions in the case of comments containing certain trigger words (obscenities, "what have you tried"-style phrases, I forget the others) where a single community flag can immediately delete a comment even without moderator involvement. None of your recent comments have been subject to that, but it is a possibility. That still requires someone to manually flag the comment.

As for notifications about flagged comments, that only happens when a moderator sees a problematic trend in these comments and manually writes a message describing the problem. The system doesn't automatically warn you about deleted comments, just as you are not notified about deleted questions or answers.

Comment: Can I ask what is wrong with "what have you tried"? I use it from time to time and don't want to make more work for you.

Comment: @talex Effort is only required for homework question, I think? (source: help center)

Comment: @user202729 I don't understand where you going? You mean that people shouldn't put any effort in question other than homework?

Comment: @talex A few questions are ok without effort, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do ...

Comment: @user202729 thanks. I think I got it. Sometime "what have you tried" is not appropriate comment. My first thought was that it is **always** inappropriate.

Comment: I'm confused by this. Asking what people have tried is often an important step in diagnosing a problem.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. Maybe I could have accessed the information you present myself, have to check the info on my profile again. Just to avoid a misunderstanding, there was no hidden "where are my comments gone?" complaint, I was just curious about how stuff works behind the scences

Comment: @user202729 i think both questions you link do demonstrate some effort by the asker ("there doesn't seem to be one" implies the user already did some research, the other answer has a detailed example), though I get your point.

Comment: @user202729 Effort is obviously _always_ required.

Comment: @MichaelKay yes, but today, diagnosing a problem is not as important as *being welcoming*. And “being welcoming” has been defined as not to give new users any hints about why they don’t get answers.

Comment: @talex This may give you an idea of why the question is not particularly helpful: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122986/is-it-ok-to-leave-what-have-you-tried-comments

Comment: @talex there is nothing wrong with asking "what have you tried?" the point is that when the comment gets addressed and details have been provided about what has been tried, then the initial comment becomes noise and no longer needed, thus a no longer needed flag is raised, Brad's point was that these don't need special moderator intervention so they can be automatically deleted without increasing the moderator workload

Comment: "...'what have you tried'-style phrases..." It's **extremely** disappointing that this is considered a "trigger." While there might be instances where it doesn't make sense, these are few and far between. The vast majority of questions need to show some research effort. If SO doesn't like the *phasing* people are using, they should find a better way of dealing with it than turning it into some kind of automatic moderation trigger. It's not rude to tell users to live up to quality standards.

Comment: Just so my inbox doesn't keep getting filled about this, the activation of single-flag deletes on "what have you tried"-style wording [was activated in 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760/135615) as a result of the discussion linked there. This has been the case for a long time, and I have no control over this. If you'd like to discuss this, feel free to do so in another Meta question that references that previous discussion, but I think this is getting a little off track from the core topic here.

Answer (score 7):

> is it common practice that comments get deleted even though they are not flagged? (maybe because a different comment on the same question/answer got flagged and in the process of cleaning up also other comments get deleted?)

It's rare (not impossible, but rare) for a mod to delete a comment that they didn't come across as a result of a flag, but it *is* common for them to respond to flags on a comment by deleting all comments under the post, or all of the comments in that particular line of discussion (if they feel that there's a series of comments on the same topic that's either inappropriate, or no longer relevant after deletion of the inappropriate comments).  You can be pretty confident that either the comment was flagged, or other comments on that post were flagged, if it was deleted.

> do I get a notification when one of my comments gets flagged or deleted because it was flagged?

No.  In *very* serious situations, where moderators find a pattern of very inappropriate behavior they may choose to send a moderator message to you about the *numerous* comments of yours deleted for a reason that they'll explain to you.  But very few deleted comments result in this, most are just silently deleted.

> did anything change recently that made moderators delete comments more frequently than before?

The data to say empirically isn't public.  I don't think moderators are materially changing how they handle comment flags.  They *have* made numerous changes recently (some technical, some not) to try to get people to cast more flags (which *would* result in more deletions), and they've done more to make it clear to users that they've been *very* liberal in what types of comments they're willing to delete *for quite some time*.  This isn't a change in how they handle flags so much as a lot of more recent attention and *publicity* to how they handle flags (which affects both how many flags people cast, and also may result in people noticing how mods are handling comment flags more than before).  They've said that they're not changing how they handle comment flags, and my anecdotal experience has been that they're correct, and that this is how they've been handling flags for a long time.

Answer (score 3):

A short answer to supplement the already excellent existing answers.

There has been an increase in comment flagging, resulting in an increase in comment deletion.

This post goes into depth about it across the network:

[Can we have some statistics on the potential change in rate of comment flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313872/310756)

This post may also be helpful for anyone wanting to delve into the statistics:

[When is a comment hostile or unfriendly? (Educating newer users how to flag comments)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373801/3956566)

Answer (score 2):

Comments are pretty much only deleted by non-authors if flagged.

- The presence of certain words can cause comments to be instantly deletable by a single flag
- Multiple flags can cause comments to be deleted
- Moderators can delete comments but only take action when they are flagged to do so.

There's no notification, after all if your comment was flagged we don't want to encourage you to write it again and again and again. That has happened, the user doing it was eventually suspended when they refused to stop despite moderators asking them not to repost the same comment repeatedly.

Only someone with access to the underlying database could tell whether comments are being deleted more frequently now than in the past. This would only be because they are being flagged more often. That may be the case with the new flag text/options for comments and the various [meta/blog posts about whether Stack Overflow is welcoming or not](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/).

Comment: Also multiple flags from non-mods will delete comments, and a single flag from a non-mod will delete a post containing blacklisted words.

Comment: yes. @Servy and sometimes just one flag will auto delete a comment with some blacklisted words. I don't think a lot of people realise that.