# Unfriendly or Unkind flag declined

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, comment-flags, unfriendly-or-unkind

Not to feed a fed horse, but I flagged this comment last night:

[image: This is why we expect questioners to put in some effort before asking.]

And it was subsequently declined:

[image: unfriendly or unkind flag by Kyle Mit declined.]

As it happens, the comment has since been deleted, but I'm curious why this was not an appropriate use of this flag?  This does not feel friendly or kind.

The original post in question was my own, but I can assure you a non-trivial amount of debugging went into reducing the question into an actual **MCVE**, to dismiss that effort as non-existent without knowing the path to get there is extremely unfriendly to new users who face a much steeper and longer diagnostic wall compared to veterans.

Comment: The comment feels blunt, all right. Whoever it was directed to probably didn't want to hear it. However, that is not enough to warrant that kind of flag, since it directly assumes poor intent.

Comment: If you spent 3 hours working on a project, handed it to your boss, and they said "I expected to you at least have put in some effort", would you regard that comment as friendly?  Would you regard it as welcoming to new users?

Comment: That comment is uninformative and condescending. I agree with your flag.

Comment: Even if we disagree if the comment is unfriendly or unkind, with a *no longer needed* flag that comment should have been nuked as well as it is not about the post but about the user.

Comment: That is one perspective. We can only dig deeper if you provide additional context. Extrapolating, I'd say that the question had issues to the point of compromising its position in the site and wasting the time of experts willing to look into it. And _this_, on the other end of the spectrum, can also be perceived as unwelcoming.

Comment: Lemme play devil's advocate here, but isn't the new CoC explicitly against "No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language"? This falls smack against it, and wasn't acted on flag wise? it seems like that comment is a putdown, not even subtle. I feel like there's a lack of consistency flag-wise (may just be an impression, mind you) when it comes to "unkind" flags...

Comment: @E_net4wisheshappyholidays, I originally didn't provide the link to the question, not to obfuscate the quality of the original post, but to not drag anyone through the mud or get bogged down in the details justifying effort. Here's [**the link to the post**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17356653/1366033), but I'm not sure it's germane to how comments like this would be perceived to new users

Comment: That comment does not feel like it was made directly in response to the answer. Are there other comments before? It feels like a response to "Oh darn! Spotted the typo" or "Oh I hadn't read the documentation". (Not implying that you did not)

Comment: But we *do* expect users to put effort into writing questions. Right?

Comment: Given that it's a 5 year old post, I probably would have leaned towards "It's no longer needed. This comment is outdated, conversational or not relevant to this post." Even on a brand new post today, that comment would probably be seen as sitting in the gray area between that and "unfriendly or unkind."

Comment: @user202729 Being *true* doesn't excuse you from being rude or condescending. Right?

Comment: That’s a very old comment to be flagging today as _unkind_. NLN would have gotten the comment deleted in a second.

Comment: Were you expecting to be declined? Or you always screenshot your flags?

Comment: The comment was deleted by the same moderator who declined your flag. My best guess is they didn't think it was strong enough to warrant such a flag, but was nevertheless no longer needed.

Comment: Strongly related: [Yvette's lament](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371385/allow-users-to-view-flagged-comments#comment641831_371385): "There's comments **from years ago** being flagged as unwelcoming. What are mods supposed to do with that? Retroactively impose a standard that has changed?" (my emph.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suspect this answer will be unpopular and I don't blame people, as it's a convoluted jungle of reasoning.

It's worth mentioning that the comment was under your own question and the comment was made by someone who is not usually rude. And for some context, this is the comment in  situ:

[image]

I  agree with the reasons [Felix mentions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378324/3956566), I declined the flag, but deleted the comment as no longer needed.  The comment was blunt, but one that no one seemed to object to 5.5 years ago. It's hard to know how to retroactively handle these issues.

So this is my philosophy.

When a person flags a comment from years ago as rude or unkind, if it is in any way a ball line comment or it is something that was commonplace from years ago, I decline the flag and delete the comment. Declined comment flags do not affect the flagger at all.

An accumulation of helpful unkind/rude flags trigger another auto flag that mods then have to deal with. So I look at the comment within that context. Is the comment bad enough to warrant going through that user's history. I have [asked for the unkind flags to not count towards this auto flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313758/310756).

There almost needs to be a statute of limitations on comments, it's rare we find truly abominable comments sitting on the site for years and the culture of the site has changed. It's like retroactively booking people for speeding tickets, because the speed limit was reduced. Maybe not the best example, but I really need coffee.

These two comments sum up my thinking:

> Gotta be honest, I think we should have an amnesty date for comments posted before this whole welcoming thing started. I understand that you have always wanted us to be civil, but let's look forward. Don't consider the things that we have done before this welcoming push. I don't want to have to go through and delete all my old comments out of the worry that I might have been less than welcoming in the past. – [zero298](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/691711/zero298)

and

> @zero298 so do I. There's comments from years ago being flagged as unwelcoming. What are mods supposed to do with that? Retroactively impose a standard that has changed? - [Yvette Colomb](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3956566/yvette-colomb)

One curiosity, why did you have a screenshot of the comment?

Comment: "why did you have a screenshot" - oh, i don't know.  Nothing inherently nefarious I think.  It's just a lossy process where I can't really go back and sanity check the copy against my own expectations in the case where it is deleted.  I regularly defend SO as a welcoming place because I overwhelmingly think it is.  I'm honestly surprised at how many people here seem to view that comment as friendly.  Is the site better off with it... no.  Does it set a good example.... no. Should the commenter be punished... no. Is it unfriendly... yep, and I'm surprised that's such a controversial stance.

Comment: I happen to also safe-keep some of the comments I flag, because right now, as exhibited here, this kind of flag is a bit like a mine field: we don't always know whether it's merited nor what to expect from it, and if we don't save declined flags, no one will learn from them.

Comment: @KyleMit The subtext of these "why did you take a screenshot" questions is to  imply that you knew the flag would get declined. You shouldn't be in a position to defend yourself though. This is Meta. Its essence is discussion. There is nothing wrong with anticipating an outcome and wanting to discuss it.

Comment: @ayhan, yeah, agreed. I screenshot lots of things that I never end up dredging out again just as a way to refer back to something that may not persist and reread it with a fresh pair of eyes and a charitable interpretation.  I also agree that meta is the appropriate place to have that subsequent discussion, despite the community's voting pattern suggesting it's not.  The flag option doesn't say, "Unfriendly and also please punish this user on my behalf" in which case I might think twice in the future.

Comment: The votes in this question don't necessarily mean that the question is bad. Voting just works differently on Meta.

Comment: @KyleMit part of the issues is: Why did you wait 5.5 years to flag it? Flags have existed for years. The "not Constructive" flag would have covered it. The comment is deleted. A declined comment flag doesn't count towards flag bans. So there's no harm done. Yes there will be issues, as these are grey areas.

Comment: @YvetteColomb, "Why did you wait to flag it?" This wasn't some backburnered thing that I was hoping to get around to some day. I didn't have a calendar appointment.  It bugged me at the time, but I didn't really have the tools to address it, and had entirely forgotten about it.  I was searching for another one of my answers on `notepad++` and stumbled across it and found the comment out of alignment with the current standards.  I think this somehow reads like some masterful plan, but it's just a day in the life. I was curious about why the flag was declined so I can flag better in the future.

Comment: @KyleMit essentially there was nothing wrong with the flag. There's a problem with how the system deals with these flags. It's the auto flags that are raised from marking them helpful. I don't see the value in tripping auto flags for comments that are years old. so it's a conundrum. When the team is back from holidays I intend to address it.

Comment: Very interesting; I also came here because my flag was rejected (the comment is 2 years old and says nothing other than the mild put-down 'you got rekt'). Looks like there's no need to use this flag until SO fixes the 'full user history review just because of rudeness' problem. I will just use the 'no longer needed' flag instead.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn the no longer needed flag is the safest. Unless something is really rude.

Answer (score 5):

I think a key point to address here is the age of the comment. Of course, it being old does not mean a user was right to be mean years ago, but it does mean that said user should not be punished today for comments they made years ago.

I'm happy to be corrected, but I do think that unfriendly (and, to a greater extent, abusive) flags incur a severe penalty for the flaggee.

As such, old comments such as those are better served being flagged as no longer needed than unfriendly, and have better chance to be marked as helpful.

Comment: I think that makes sense to place flags/comments in the context of an evolving Code of Conduct.  I was not aware of the increased penalty from flagging some types over others, and really just looking for the right bucket to describe this type of comment... 'unfriendly' still applies in my mind.  So is the flagger supposed to know that recent comments are the type of thing that can be considered unfriendly, but old comments should use 'No Longer Needed' instead?  Is it worth removing the unfriendly option on old comments, if we don't intend to consistently enforce it on older posts?

Comment: Good question @Kyle. Realistically, I don't believe we'll see personalized flag options based on the age of a comment, but that could be a good idea. I think the usual communicating with people on meta will be the way to share and exchange opinions on that for the time being.

Answer (score 3):

I think that particular flag was waste of moderators' time and I agree with decline.

The flag was on comment to a post that have 197 view over 5 years (I suspect non-trivial part of views is due to this meta question). The question itself caused by essentially typo (invisible character) and really can be just deleted without any problem for the site. The comment while not exactly the friendliest one but not really offensive either.

What I think should happen when you find such an old comment on an old post - improve Q&A and flag "moderator attention":

- review question for being on-topic or answer being good quality. If there are comments that need to be inlined  do so (include half sentence for each comment into flag's description). Flag comment for "moderator attention" with text like "delete all comments, *this* and *that* inlined, the rest are no longer needed"
- if question/answer deserve to be closed/deleted vote appropriately. See if flagging to bulk-delete comments is appropriate (most likely). If it is your own post and you can't delete it (like in this case due to upvoted answer) - flag post for moderator attention with comment "delete the post which is not useful because ....(typographical error in this case), I can't do myself due to upvoted answer". To my knowledge there will be no reputation loss for really old questions like this.
- if there really nothing need to be done and there is only one old comment you think should be removed - flag as "no longer needed" - to my understanding this requires significantly less time from moderators as for most cases its is clearly not useful comment (and they still can elevate it to whatever other level/investigation if the comment considered truly offensive).
- finally if everything is ok but the comment if really bad (how could it survived for so long?) flagging as "unkind" sounds fine.

Comment: Plus the time taken to address meta. That's more time consuming than anything.

Comment: @YvetteColomb, if you have norman doors, people are going to keep trying them to open them the wrong way, and it's not necessarily the user's fault.. The flag text says 'Unfriendly' ✓.  The copy doesn't mimic the justifications provided in this thread: "shouldn't punish contributors", "consumes mod time", "standards have changed".  So if someone's not intimately familiar with meta (and flagging isn't hidden behind some level of meta rep), it seems like this'll continue to come up.

Comment: @KyleMit yes it will. Also what is unkind is subjective to some extent. The thing is, it does the flagger no harm to have a declined comment flag. There's no imposed flagging restrictions. And the flags are usually declined and deleted if borderline cases. So there's no harm done. There's a lot of questions about comment flags being declined or comments being deleted on meta. Many people don't check if their comment flags have been declined, they notice the comment is gone.