# Comment on question from new user and declined "Unfriendly or unkind" flag

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, comment-flags, unfriendly-or-unkind

I flagged a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55186732/valueerror-not-enough-values-to-unpack-expected-2-got-0-brokers-topic-sy) this morning. The question contains an image of the poster's code. The comment reads

> Why would you post an *image of code* rather than the code itself...

This is on a new user's first question (they created their account half an hour before posting their question).

Before flagging, I had read the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct#unfriendly-language) page, which states

> **No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language.**
>
> Even if you don’t intend it, this can have a negative impact on others.

and gives examples of unfriendly comments:

> “You could Google this in 5 seconds.”
>
> “If you bothered to read my question, you’d know it’s not a duplicate.”
>
> “Are you speaking English? If so, I can’t tell.”
>
> “I came to get help, not to get my question edited.”

This comment looks to me like the exact definition of a subtle put-down, especially with the use of italics, and an ellipsis.
It was probably written by somebody who is tired of seeing bad questions (which is understandable), but keep in mind that this is the very first thing that the OP sees in response to their post.

In comparison, the next comment is what I would expect in response to a new user:

> Please don't post images of your code! Please construct a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

This is the kind of comment that conveys the right information without the snark in my opinion.

As you can guess, my flag has been declined. I am struggling to see why and I far as I can see, I don't have a way to contact the person who handled the flag.

I did read [When is a comment hostile or unfriendly? (Educating newer users how to flag comments)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373801/when-is-a-comment-hostile-or-unfriendly-educating-newer-users-how-to-flag-comm), where the reasons for declining the flags seem pretty clear to me.

I also read [Unfriendly or Unkind flag declined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378323/unfriendly-or-unkind-flag-declined), which is about a years-old post. I can see the arguments there, but they don't apply here.

I really think this kind of comments is a problem. It's not outrageous (not as harsh as the examples in the CoC), but it gives a bad first impression of the site. I can see why people could be reluctant to participate in SO if that's what they see a minute after their first post.

I am curious to have other opinions about this particular issue (subtle put-down on very first post) and how other people would have handled the flag.

Should I expect similar flags to be declined as well unless the comment is downright rude? Should I revise my definition of unwelcoming?

---

#### About the fact that it's the user's first post

I would like to clarify why I insisted on the fact that it was the user's first post. I don't mean that there should be different standards for first posts. We do agree that a rude comment is rude no matter who it is addressed to.

I wanted to point out that the *consequences* of a rude comment to a newbie are worse.

A user who has spent some time on SO (even just somebody like me with a few posts and ~100 rep) has seen several posts and comments and realized that 99%+ of comments are not rude.

If tomorrow I post a question and the first comment is something like "well, clearly you haven't done any research" I will probably brush it off as that person being part of the <1%. It's very unlikely that I will decide to leave the site.

But if it's my very first time on the site, I'm much more likely to be put off.

If one of my friends says something rude to me for the first time, I'm more likely to think that they are having a bad day. If I meet somebody for the first time and the very first thing they tell me is rude, I'm more likely to avoid interacting with them in the future.

**So to summarize, all rude/condescending comments are problematic. But the ones addressed to new users have a higher chance to result in a user leaving the site.**

I have read on meta that SO has a problem keeping its users. The way I see it, such comments are a big part of the problem. Low-level, frequent attacks are not a big deal individually, but they do amount to something.

Comment: An ellipsis is rude, but an exclamation point is good? Which flag, precisely, did you use?

Comment: "*subtle put-down on very first post*" I don't know why it matters if it is the "very first post" or the twentieth. If the comment is inappropriate, then it's inappropriate. We don't have different standards for what is and is not OK.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Oh no, I also think they could have done without the exclamation mark. But I do think the ellipsis is worse, I find that it makes the comment sound like "how could you be so stupid...", whereas the exclamation mark makes it sound more like "Be careful, you did something wrong and your question might not be answered!". To me, anyway. To be clear, I wouldn't have used either. I used the "It's unfriendly or unkind." flag.

Comment: The ellipsis is inconsequential.  This, on the other hand: ヽ(ಠ_ಠ)ノ

Comment: This. This is the reason why I avoid posting questions on StackOverflow. 99% of the time, I get people giving me grief and downvoting my questions instead of helping. 

Everytime I post on Stackoverflow, i expect to get put down or given stupid answers like "google it" or "you should improve yourself" instead of being helped. 

This community has a lot of users thinking they are really smart and should not help. 

Searching on google and finding answers on stackoverflow is great! but god forbid you post a question, cause you will get screwed

Comment: @KelvinChong ..and there is the most common problem with abuse of SO - the belief that it's a personal helpdesk that provides free work.  The plan is not to help just you, but generate new and useful Q&A for those who follow.

Comment: @MartinJames of course, there are differences between people looking for 100% code with zero effort and there are people that clearly made an effort but is stuck on one specific problem. I always google and try my best and only use SO as the last last last options.

Comment: Given the fact that all the answers have addressed the one comment I flagged instead of the general trend I was trying to point out, I probably didn't do a very good job at explaining the problem... I may try to present it differently in a different post, later

Answer (score 12):

Let's start with this. We do not have different standards of behavior for new posts. It *does not matter* whether this comment was made towards a new user or a 10 year veteran. Either the comment is appropriate or it isn't. So your discussion of the fact that this was posted on a question by a new user is irrelevant.

Second, to me, the statement itself doesn't really fit into the same box as "You could Google this in 5 seconds." (which implies laziness) or "Are you speaking English? If so, I can’t tell." (which is just straight-up being a jerk). It is certainly a rhetorical question that shows frustration on the part of the one making the statement. But I don't think it carries the sting that these other statements do. Indeed, the ellipsis at the end seems to me to suggest confusion rather than accusation.

It's not a great comment, but I don't think it's in the same domain as the others.

Comment: Actually, I agree with your first paragraph - see my edit :) We may understand the comment in different ways. Well, that's exactly why I posted this question!

Answer (score 5):

> In comparison, the next comment is what I would expect in response to a new user:
>
> > Please don't post images of your code! Please construct a MCVE.

Actually, that is a worse comment than the one you flagged. Let's examine it:

> Why would you post an image of code rather than the code itself...

It's actually pretty good. Why, indeed, would a user post an image of code, **when they could post the code itself?** Not only does it express the emotion of the poster, which is a totally valid thing, but it also explains what should have been done instead.

In comparison, your comment is some kind of "meta" comment; it does no address the problem, but only vagualy asks not to do something. It is not clear that the second sentence is in any way related to the first, and that posting an MCVE would solve the code-in-image problem.

---

I would also like to address something here:

## Adding "please" to a post does not make it more respectful.

Respect happens in your head. It's a thing that you feel towards another individual. You could be saying "please", "kindfully" and "thanks" everywhere, and that is in no way an indication of either respect, welcoming-ness, or whatever positive.

If you can't construct a sentence without "please" that is not welcoming or respectful, it will not magically become so because you add it.

> Don't post images of your code! Construct a MCVE.

Is nothing close to welcoming, respectful or friendly.

Comment: Indeed.  "Please, go f**k yourself" is not an improvement.

Comment: @RobertHarvey [With all due respect doesn't magically improve things either.](https://assets.amuniversal.com/6e402250a080012f2fe600163e41dd5b)

Comment: To clarify, I didn't write the "Please" comment and I shouldn't have made it sound like that's what I would have written. I also very much agree that adding "please" to a post doesn't make it more respectful. And yes, the comment I flagged does provide a solution, and it's a great comment _except for the tone_ (hence the 'subtle put-down'). The commenter could easily have said "Could you [please] post your code instead of a picture of it?" It conveys the same information and it sounds a lot nicer to me.

Comment: Except that *there's no tone* but the one you heard.  For what it's worth, I would have also declined your flag.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Having other people's opinions about the flag is the reason why I posted here :)